# Show hidden files in cloud9.io

Tags: cloud9-ide, hidden-files

I am developing a node.js application with cloud9 online IDE. I need to edit the .gitignore file, but I can not see it because it is a hidden file.
Does anybody knows how to show hidden files in the cloud9 file tree?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to upper left Cloud9 menu item, then select the **preferences** option.

In the settings, select tree & navigate, and then you can modify the pattern of hidden files.

To show all, yo can erase all the text box, to see the `.gitignore` file, delete only the ".*" in the pattern. This will make the `.gitignore` file appear in the file tree.

Comment: I've tryed and it works, at least in this version of C9 (Sept-2015): Version 3.0.2515 (502040ee47)

Answer (score 47):

The method described in the other answer permanently modifies  the pattern for files which cloud9 will consider hidden. There is also a quick way to temporarily display hidden files.
In the upper corner of the tree there is a gear button which opens a popup with an option to show hidden file

[image: tree options popup]

Comment: this was way easier!! ty